# checking if row was inserted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, insert

I am trying to check whether a row is getting inserted into my database. It is throwing an error even when it does insert (it's a database issue that will get resolved later when I get a newer version of Microsoft Access), so I can't check whether the insert is successful based on whether there's an error or not. I think I need to check the AffectedRows of something, but I'm not sure what. I've been looking for info on how to do this but I can't figure out how to make it work for my exact situation. Here's a general idea of what my code looks like:

```
Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick

'code for collecting data...

'Define Connection
    Dim myConn As New OleDbConnection
    myConn.ConnectionString = AccessDataSource1.ConnectionString
    myConn.Open()

    'Insert command
    Dim myIns1 As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tableCourse 'long insert command here...

'Execute command and handle errors
    Try
        myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch myException5 As Exception
    End Try

    'Close connection
    myConn.Close()
```

-UPDATE-

I tried it like this:

```
'Execute command, handle errors, and check if row was inserted
    Dim numInserted As Integer = 0
    Try
        numInserted = myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch myException As Exception
    Finally
        If numInserted = 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "Sorry, an error occured."
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Thank you! Your new course approval request has been submitted."
        End If
    End Try
```

But the numInserted is coming out as 0 every time even though the insert is successful. It may have to do with the fact that myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery() throws an error even though the insert is successful.

-EDIT- I discovered that the "duplicate values" error is because it is somehow attempting to insert the record twice. I have no idea why it's doing that though.

Comment: I'm using Access 2003 which for some reason is throwing a quirky error about duplicate values, I looked around online to try to figure out what was going on and all the information I could find on it said that it was just a weird quirk (there was some fix for it when working directly in Access) and that it exists in 2007 also but not 2010. So I'm planning to update my database to Access 2010 as soon as I can.

Comment: "Access 2003 which for some reason is throwing a quirky error about duplicate values," - duplicate rows are duplicate rows. Are you sure this is a bug? Have you tried compacting and repairing your database?

Comment: Haven't tried doing anything to it; I probably should. It's pretty weird because it says there are duplicate rows every time it inserts, even though there aren't. I'm no expert on Access though, all I know is what I found online.

Comment: @Sara: Take a backup, and then compact and repair. sounds like you might have some corruption...

Comment: For testing purposes are you aware of the primary key value you're attempting to insert or does this table have an AutoNumber field?

Comment: @Jeff No it doesn't have an AutoNumber field, I just have a primary key field and validation that checks for duplicates.

Comment: @Mitch Compact and repair seemed to work, thanks!

Comment: @Sara: I thought it might given the symptoms. I'll add as an answer.

Comment: Actually unfortunately I was wrong, it just didn't throw an error at first because it wasn't inserting at all (I messed something up). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) function returns the affected number of rows...

```
Dim numInserted as Integer = myIns1.ExecuteNonQuery()
If numInserted = 0 Then
   ' no rows were inserted...throw exception?
End If
```

Comment: Seems like that should work, but it's coming out as 0 every time.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you are describing (known no duplicates, but inserts throw duplicate errors) sound like your Access database needs [Compacting and Repairing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/help-prevent-and-correct-database-file-problems-by-using-compact-and-repair-HA010235583.aspx).

You should do this on a regular basis. (Always backup up first).